# NelmioApiDocBundle generates extra inputs when using FormType with nested forms

Tags: forms, symfony, nested, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm using to use NelmioApiDocBundle to generate API documentation. The problem is when I use FormType with nested forms or buttons (submit /cancel), I get extra parameters. This is my FormType:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('user', new UserType());
    $builder->add('contact', new ContactType()));
    $builder->add('Valider', 'submit'),
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'registration';
}

}
```

And in my controller :

```
/**
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *     input = {"class"="BundleNamespace\...\RegistrationFormType", "name" = ""} 
 * )
 */
public function putAction(Request $request){
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGooa.png)

How can I remove these extra parameters (user, contact, Valider) ?